# How to update a column for a set of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The below query gives a set of rows with 3 columns.

```
Select 
    c.CaseID, i.ImageID, i.ImagePath
From 
    tblCase c WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join  
    tblName n WITH (NOLOCK) on c.CaseID = n.CaseID 
inner join 
    tblImage i WITH (NOLOCK) on n.NameID = i.NameID
where 
    n.NameCode = '70'
```

The ImagePath column will have data like this with semi colon separated values.

```
ImageID=3215;FilePath=\2016\5\13\test.tif;ImageType=Original;PageNumber=1
```

The ImageType value needs to be changed to "duplicate" as below for all the rows returned from the query.

```
ImageID=3215;FilePath=\2016\5\13\test.tif;ImageType=duplicate;PageNumber=1
```

Any ideas? Is using a cursor good to do this kind of update? The number of rows will be a couple of thousands.

Thank you!

Comment: is `ImageType=Original` fixed on all the rows for that column?

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: No, it is not fixed. I will have to check if it has ImageType=Original and only change those rows. Thank you!

Comment: Will be pain in plain sql. Better do a clr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea would be to stop storing multiple values in one column and normalize the database so that you don't run into issues like this.

Barring that, you can try to use `REPLACE()`, but you need to be very careful that you don't inadvertently change parts of the string that happen to match with your string.

```
REPLACE(ImagePath, ';ImageType=Original;', ';ImagetType=Duplicate;')
```

might work, but if that attribute can appear at the end of the string (without a trailing semicolon) then it might fail. It could also fail if there is a space in between the "=" and the attribute/value in some cases. It could also fail if it might be the first attribute without a leading semicolon. There might be some other possible failure cases as well - which is why this isn't how you should be storing your data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try:

```
declare @s varchar(max) = 'ImageID=3215;FilePath=\2016\5\13\test.tif;ImageType=original;PageNumber=1'

select substring(@s, 0, charindex('imagetype=', @s)) + 'ImageType=duplicate' +
       substring(@s, charindex(';', @s, charindex('imagetype=',@s)), len(@s))
```

http://rextester.com/edit/AVQO58898

Description: take everything till `imagetype=` and add `ImageType=duplicate` to it and add everything from first semicolon that occurs after`imagetype=` till the end.

Answer (score -2):

Use `REPLACE`

```
UPDATE i
SET i.ImagePath = REPLACE(i.ImagePath, ';ImageType=Original;', ';ImageType=duplicate;')
From tblCase c WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join tblName n WITH (NOLOCK) on c.CaseID = n.CaseID 
inner join tblImage i WITH (NOLOCK) on n.NameID = i.NameID
where n.NameCode = '70'
```

Comment: This will cause some pretty big issues if "Original" happens to appear anywhere else in the column.

Comment: @TomH It could be modified obviously to replace ;ImageType=Original;